# react.js foreach variable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do I get record is not defined in the console? It also doesnt print any value

```
this.props.records.forEach(function(record){ 
      numbers.push(        
        <tr key={record.id} >
          <td>{record.title}</td>
        </tr>)
      })
```

Error in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: record is not definedReact.createClass.onChange @ Inline JSX script:137React.createClass.changeHandler @ Inline JSX script:82ReactClass.createClass._handleChange @ react-with-addons.js:9067executeDispatch @ react-with-addons.js:3307forEachEventDispatch @ react-with-addons.js:3295executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-with-addons.js:3316executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-with-addons.js:2689forEachAccumulated @ react-with-addons.js:19368EventPluginHub.processEventQueue @ react-with-addons.js:2896runEventQueueInBatch @ react-with-addons.js:11161ReactEventEmitterMixin.handleTopLevel @ react-with-addons.js:11187handleTopLevelImpl @ react-with-addons.js:11273Mixin.perform @ react-with-addons.js:18340ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ react-with-addons.js:9613batchedUpdates @ react-with-addons.js:16573ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent @ react-with-addons.js:11367
```

Comment: Could you copy/paste the original error?

Comment: In which line error has appeared?

Comment: Updated the question with the error in console.

Comment: Add `console.log(records)` right before and see if any are undefined

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your array contains some `undefined` values (e.g. `[{id: 1}, undefined, {id: 2}]`).

```
console.log(this.props.records);
// or set a debugger statement to inspect the state
```